# Solve equation with exponential term

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, logarithm, equation-solving

I have the equation 1 = ((π r<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n</sup>) / n! ∙ e<sup>(-π r<sup>2</sup>)</sup>

I want to solve it using MATLAB. Is the following the correct code for doing this? The answer isn't clear to me.

```
n= 500;
A= 1000000;
d= n / A;
f= factorial( n );
solve (' 1 = ( d * pi * r^2 )^n / f  . exp(- d * pi * r^2) ' , 'r')
```

The answer I get is:

```
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
k = Z_ intersect Dom::Interval([-(PI/2 -
Im(log(`fexp(-PI*d*r^2)`)/n)/2)/(PI*Re(1/n))], (PI/2 +
Im(log(`fexp(-PI*d*r^2)`)/n)/2)/(PI*Re(1/n)))

> In solve at 190 

ans =

    (fexp(-PI*d*r^2)^(1/n))^(1/2)/(pi^(1/2)*d^(1/2)*exp((pi*k*(2*i))/n)^(1/2))
   -(fexp(-PI*d*r^2)^(1/n))^(1/2)/(pi^(1/2)*d^(1/2)*exp((pi*k*(2*i))/n)^(1/2))
```

Comment: I would recomment you go readup on the documentation for MATLAB, from what I see there is quite a bit of helpful docs

Comment: I'd be curious about the answer it gives, but I don't have MATLAB installed. It would be nice to add this to your question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer - I've run the code on my end and I've updated the OP's post.  It doesn't make much sense to me either.

Comment: Here's [the solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%3D+%28%28%CF%80+r2%29^n%29+%2F+n!+%E2%88%99+e^%28-%CF%80+r2%29) for reference; not exactly a nice expression, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You have several issues with your code.

**1.** First, you're evaluating some parts in floating-point. This isn't always bad as long as you know the solution will be exact. However, `factorial(500)` overflows to `Inf`. In fact, for [`factorial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html), anything bigger than `170` will overflow and any input bigger than `21` is potentially inexact because the result will be larger than [`flintmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html). This calculation should be preformed symbolically via [`sym/factorial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/factorial.html):

```
n = sym(500);
f = factorial(n);
```

which returns an integer approximately equal to `1.22e1134` for `f`.

**2.** You're using a period (`'.'`) to specify multiplication. In [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html), upon which most of the symbolic math functions are based, a period is [shorthand for concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/_concat.html).

Additionally, as is stated in the R2015a documentation (and possibly earlier):

> String inputs will be removed in a future release. Use `syms` to declare the variables instead, and pass them as a comma-separated list or vector.

If you had not used a string, I don't think that it would have been possible for your command to get misinterpreted and return such a confusing result. Here is how you could use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) with symbolic variables:

```
syms r;
n = sym(500);
A = sym(1000000);
d = n/A;
s = solve(1==(d*sym(pi)*r^2)^n/factorial(n)*exp(-d*sym(pi)*r^2),r)
```

which, after several minutes, returns a 1,000-by-1 vector of solutions, all of which are complex. As @BenVoigt suggests, you can try the `'Real'` option for [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#zmw57dd0e107614). However, in R2015a at least, the four solutions returned in terms of `lambertw` don't appear to actually be real.

Comment: I didn't mention that `f` became `Inf` because it wan't being used by the solve call anyway, a problem I considered more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to note:

1. MATLAB is not using the values of `A`, `d`, and `f` from your workspace.
2. `f . exp` is not doing at all what you wanted, which was multiplication.  It's instead becoming an unknown function `fexp`
3. Passing additional options of `'Real', true` to `solve` gets rid of most of these extraneous conditions.

You probably should avoid calling the version of `solve` which accepts a string, and use the Symbolic Toolbox instead (`syms 'r'`)